# NotifyDataSetChanged not working after scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontallist, notifydatasetchanged

I have implemented HorizontalListView ([from here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)) inside ScrollView.
The HorizontalListView does support `madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, but when I am scrolling horizontally and then clicking a button to call my next data items, they are not displayed. They are being **appended** to the rest of the rows (as it only has one `DataSetObserver`)

How can I display my appended item in a row even after it is scrolled?

Or how to refresh my layout - I already tried `invalidate()` and `requestlayout()`.

Here is the code of my `HorizontalListView` Class.

```
public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

    public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
    protected int mCurrentX;
    protected int mNextX;
    private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
    protected Scroller mScroller;
    private GestureDetector mGesture;
    private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
    private boolean mDataChanged = false;


    public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private synchronized void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = -1;
        mRightViewIndex = 0;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mCurrentX = 0;
        mNextX = 0;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }





    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
        mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }



    @Override
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
    }

    private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
                mDataChanged = true;
            }
            invalidate();
        //  initView();
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            reset();
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if(mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        reset();
    }

    private synchronized void reset(){
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        //TODO: implement
    }

    private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
        LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
        if(params == null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }

        addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
        child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }



    @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    //  if (mCurrentX == 0 && mNextX == 0 && mMaxX == 0)
    //      mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(mAdapter == null){
            return;
        }

        if(mDataChanged){
            int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
            initView();
            removeAllViewsInLayout();
            mNextX = oldCurrentX;
            mDataChanged = false;
        }



        if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
            int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
            mNextX = scrollx;
        }

        if(mNextX <= 0){
            mNextX = 0;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
            mNextX = mMaxX;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }

        int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

        removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
        fillList(dx);
        positionItems(dx);

        mCurrentX = mNextX;

        if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
            post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fillList(final int dx) {
        int edge = 0;
        View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getRight();
        }
        fillListRight(edge, dx);

        edge = 0;
        child = getChildAt(0);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getLeft();
        }
        fillListLeft(edge, dx);


    }

    private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
        while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

            View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
            rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

            if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
                mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
            }

            if (mMaxX < 0) {
                mMaxX = 0;
            }
            mRightViewIndex++;
        }

    }

    private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
        while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
            View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
            leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mLeftViewIndex--;
            mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    }

    private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
            mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mLeftViewIndex++;
            child = getChildAt(0);

        }

        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mRightViewIndex--;
            child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        }
    }

    private void positionItems(final int dx) {
        if(getChildCount() > 0){
            mDisplayOffset += dx;
            int left = mDisplayOffset;
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
                left += childWidth + child.getPaddingRight();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
        mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return handled;
    }

    protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        return true;
    }

    private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
                mNextX += (int)distanceX;
            }
            requestLayout();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                    if(mOnItemClicked != null){
                        mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                    }
                    if(mOnItemSelected != null){
                        mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            int childCount = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                    if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {
                        mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        private boolean isEventWithinView(MotionEvent e, View child) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            int[] childPosition = new int[2];
            child.getLocationOnScreen(childPosition);
            int left = childPosition[0];
            int right = left + child.getWidth();
            int top = childPosition[1];
            int bottom = top + child.getHeight();
            viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
            return viewRect.contains((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());
        }
    };



}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() after you add the new items in your ListAdapter?

Comment: Yes. As the items are added into other rows. Thing I found out now, is If i don't scroll completely and click on button,items are appended. This Means i should add new items before my entire scroll is complete. Any Suggestions how to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

### Adapter

First of all, we can't see exactly how you're creating and using your adapter (`mAdapter`).  It's obviously created by another class, and passed into your `HorizontalListView`.

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/119114) to make sure you're using your adapter correctly.

### Locking

Also, it's not clear to me that you need all the `synchronized` blocks in your code.  Is something in a background thread invoking all those methods?  If not, I would remove those.  You can certainly just remove them *for test purposes*, and see if your code functions differently without them (indicating that you had a *deadlock* with the locking in place).

For example, your method:

```
public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
}
```

I have a hard time seeing how this method should be `synchronized`.  Is a background thread attempting to set the scroll for your view?  If you really are doing this from a background thread, I might suggest something like this, to be placed in your worker thread:

```
final int x = newScrollPosition;
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      horizontalListView.scrollTo(x);
   }
});
```

if you have a reference to the `activity` in your thread / runnable's `run()` method.  Alternatively, you could use:

- [View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- [View.postDelayed(Runnable,long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)
- [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html